# Scheduled event on wordpress runs only once

Tags: wordpress, schedule

I'm new in wp and I need to use wp_schedule_event.
I'm trying with this code

```
add_action( 'my_func', 'my_func');
function myFunction() {
  error_log("asd");
}

function activateSchedule($recurrence) {
  if(!wp_next_scheduled( 'my_func' )) {
    // Schedule the event
    wp_schedule_event(current_time('timestamp'), $recurrence, 'my_func' );
  }
}
```

I also create custom recurrences this way

```
function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {

  $schedules['5sec'] = array(
        'interval'  => 5,
        'display'   => __( 'Every 5 seconds', 'textdomain' )
  );
}

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval');
```

But the scheduled function runs only once. 
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but I had a similar issue: your function is missing a return statement:

```
function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {

  $schedules['5sec'] = array(
        'interval'  => 5,
        'display'   => __( 'Every 5 seconds', 'textdomain' )
  );
   return $schedules;
}
```